# How can i notify the correct tab at Firefox page-load time?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-sdk

I have built the following code with the Firefox add-on SDK that successfully adds a notification to the [`NotificationBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/notificationbox) on the current active tab, at page-load time.

How can I change it to use the parameterised version of the [`getNotificationBox()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/notificationbox#Finding_the_current_notification_box) method, in order to select the `NotificationBox` on the tab that belongs to the `Document` being loaded?

```
const observer = require( 'observer-service' );
var {Cc, Ci, Cr, Cu} = require( 'chrome' );

observer.add( 'document-element-inserted', function( document ) {
  var window = document.defaultView;
  var mainWindow = window.QueryInterface( Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor )
                     .getInterface( Ci.nsIWebNavigation )
                     .QueryInterface( Ci.nsIDocShellTreeItem )
                     .rootTreeItem
                     .QueryInterface( Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor )
                     .getInterface( Ci.nsIDOMWindow );

  var notificationBox = mainWindow.gBrowser.getNotificationBox();

  notificationBox.appendNotification(
    'This is my message', 
    'myNotifyId', 
    'chrome://global/skin/icons/information-16.png', 
    notificationBox.PRIORITY_INFO_LOW
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var notificationBox = mainWindow.gBrowser.getNotificationBox(mainWindow.gBrowser.getBrowserForDocument(document));
```

If `document` might be a frame, you would need to use `document.defaultView.top.document` instead.